# SQL multiple sql user logins and performance

Tags: sql, performance

We have a production server with about 100 databases on it. We are in the process of creating a new module that is requiring row level security for the purposes of reporting.

Security is mintained and dependant on unique logins to the sql server. This maintains db access and introduces a secure layer where users are only able to access objects and respective data at row level.

As you can see potentially there could be thousands of individual logins. The data is secured by individual user and each user is unique to a database and unique to the server.

Before we proceed.......

I would like to ask the forum the following

1. is there another way of where we can have say 100 logins instead of thousands where each login is restricted to a database and still maintain row level security.
2. if the answer to point 1 is no. What are the likely performance impacts going to be with numerous individual logins on the production server, if any?

Thank you so much in advance

With kind regards

Paul

Comment: Sounds like an odd database design :S

Comment: FaddishWorm. Can you elaborate please. If you have another solution where we are able to protect the data at row level i am all ears.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to restrict each user to specific rows within a specific database, with potentially multiple users for a database each seeing a different subset of rows? If so then presumably you do need multiple logins.

Comment: A little about the background. We are designing a custom reporting solution that allow users to create there own reports and submit these to a reporting server. The reporting server is a direct copy of the OLTP with the exception of the security layer.

Comment: Obviously we have no control on the design of the report templates created but still have a liability in controling the data presented to an individual user executing a report.The reporting solution will be on its own server and remote from the OLTP. So any reporting queries will have no effect on the OLTP servers performance. we need to control access to data at row level. Each user has there own access permissions, set to view and or maintain data on the OLTP dbase. There is no requirement to write to the reporting server only read.

Comment: We require a process of maintining the security for reporting.

Comment: The data is sensitive in nature and subject to data protection

Comment: Why does the database need to enforce the security?  Why not enforce the security at the application layer?

Comment: The reporting tool is external to the application (crystal) which has no internal security layer. we are forced to perform the security on teh dbase. We are not able to protect the date via our app for bespoke written crystal reports. We have lready explored this as an option. Thank you for the comment though

Comment: If you're replying to particular people, start your comment with `@` and their username and a space - that way, they get notified about your comment and are more likely to come back and read your reply.

Comment: @Damien_the_unbeliever Ok thankyou. Sorry for not conforming with protocol. New to the forum.